# Angular + Mongoose - data going in as single array rather than individual bits

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

(SOLUTION IN COMMENTS)

I'm on my first Angular app so please bear with me if my problem description isnt clear.

I have a Mongoose schema defined as (simplified versions of everything being shown):

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tags: Array
});
```

In Angular I making a `http post` using the code:

```
self.post = function(tags) {
    return $http.post(API + '/person', {
        tags: tags
      })
}
```

I've done a console log of tags and can confirm the content as: `["test", "test2"]`. Also on doing a `typeof` i can confirm it is an object.

However when I look at my db - I don't see each value individually displayed, instead I see as one as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Robomongo screenshot]

Could someone please help me understand what i need to do so that `test` and `test2` appear as 2 items in the array.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Found the issue - when I do a typeof during the `http.post` the `tag` variable shows as an object, however in the backend its a string.

Comment: And i fixed it using `var recreateArray = req.body.tags.split(',');` in the backend